# How to declare a list of all values in an enum in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to declare an array/list in my spring xml that contains all the values of an enum.

Let's say I have an enum in java:

```
public enum Codes {
    AAA,
    BBB,
    CCC;
}
```

I would like to do something in my spring xml like

```
<util:list id="enumValues" values="#{Codes.values()}"/
```

How can I do it? I've tried numerous combinations using EL and util:list with facory-methods etc but nothing seems to work.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? You get an error? an empty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
<bean class="Codes" factory-method="values"/>
```

and for some reason that works. The bean won't be of type `Codes` but a `Codes[]`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to get all enum constants:

```
<util:list id="enumValues" values="#{Codes.class.getEnumConstants()}"/>
```

Comment: Maybe shortened as `#{Codes.class.enumConstants}`.

Comment: This doesn't even work for me. I get an error: Attribute 'values' is not allowed to appear in element 'util:list'